# onsubmit form not working need to show some validations

Tags: javascript, html

I have few Text fields in that 2 text fields will editable  based on check box enable/disable.
When i try to submit the form with empty or incorrect format(like range ) it should show some validation and that page won't redirect to result page .but in my case it not showing any validation and it redirecting to result page.
I have tried this ,please help with this.

Thanks..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate() {
        var infc = document.getElementById("listenInterface").value;
        var gigamonport = document.getElementById("gigamonPort").value;
        var m2000port = document.getElementById("m2000Port").value;
        var ret = true;
        if (infc == "" || infc == null) {
            document.getElementById("ipErr").innerHTML = "Enter Listen Interface/IP Address.";
            alert("111");
            ret = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ipErr").innerHTML = "";
        }

        if (gigamonport == "" || gigamonport == null) {
        document.getElementById "(gigaportErr").innerHTML = "Enter TCP Listen port.";
        alert("222");
        ret = false;
        } else if (isNaN(gigamonport)) {
            document.getElementById("gigaportErr").innerHTML = "Enter only numbers for port.";
            alert("333");
            ret = false;
        } else if (gigamonport <= 0 || gigamonport > 65535) {
            document.getElementById("gigaportErr").innerHTML = "Enter only numbers in range of 0-65535 for port.";
            alert("444");
            ret = false;
        } else document.getElementById("gigaportErr").innerHTML = "";

        if (m2000port == "" || m2000port == null) {
            document.getElementById("m2000portErr").innerHTML = "Enter TCP Listen port.";
            alert("555");
            ret = false;
        } else if (isNaN(m2000port)) {
            document.getElementById("m2000portErr").innerHTML = "Enter only numbers for port.";
            alert("666");
            ret = false;
        } else if (m2000port <= 0 || m2000port > 65535) {
            document.getElementById("m2000portErr").innerHTML = "Enter only numbers in range of 0-65535 for port.";
            alert("777");
            ret = false;
        } else document.getElementById("m2000portErr").innerHTML = "";

      return ret;
    }
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="result.html" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate();">
            <input 
                type="checkbox" id="gigamonenable" name="gigamonenable" onclick="document.getElementById('gigamonPort').disabled=!this.checked;" />
            Gigamon port Enable
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="m2000enable" name="m2000enable" onclick="document.getElementById('m2000Port').disabled=!this.checked;" />
            M2000 port Enable
            <br>
        <label>Listen Interface/IP Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="listenInterface" name="listenInterface"  /><span id="ipErr" class="error"></span><br>
        <label>Gigamon Port:</label>
            <input type="text" id="gigamonPort" name="gigamonPort"  disabled="disabled" /><span id="gigaportErr" class="error"></span><br>
        <label>M2000 Port:</label>
            <input type="text" id="m2000Port" name="m2000Port"  disabled="disabled" /><span id="m2000portErr" class="error"></span>
        <br>
            <input type="submit" id ="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax error

```
if(gigamonport == "" || gigamonport == null){
document.getElementById"(gigaportErr").innerHTML = "Enter TCP Listen port.";
```

try this

```
if(gigamonport == "" || gigamonport == null){
document.getElementById("gigaportErr").innerHTML = "Enter TCP Listen port.";
```

error:

```
"(gigaportErr")
```